# Проверка по типу объекта

Tags: ооп, php

Здравствуйте, возник такой вопрос:
Имеется метод:

```
public function model($file_model) {
    $class_model = ucfirst($file_model);
    Route::$controller->$file_model = new $class_model();
}
```

Он подключает файл с классом. Само подключение реализовано через автозагрузку.
И проблема в том, что у меня может существовать одноименный файл с другим по типу классом.

Т.е. есть два класса:

```
Name_class extends Controller  
Name_class extends Model
```

Как видно имена у них одинаковые, а вот типы разные, так вот мне и нужно, чтобы при создании объекта класса Name_class, создавался именно класс с типом Model.

Comment: ИМХО, большой касяк делать ДВА файла с разным контекстом. Как вариант, переименуйте класс с контролером в что-то типа MyClassController

Comment: Да я знаю, что можно делать префиксы у файлов... допустим ко всем моделям приписывать в начало "model_" и т.д. но я хочу узнать, может быть можно в php создавать объекты по его типу...

Comment: вы делаете new ClassName и если в одном пространстве имен у вас окажется два класса с одним именем(ClassName) то вы получите ошибку.  
На случай если вы не в курсе: имя класс == тип объекта

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Да я в курсе. Видимо нет способа создать объект глядя на его родителя, очень жаль. Значит придется к каждой модели делать префикс.

Comment: @Аркадий Кожедуб А вы можете привести пример подобного в других ЯП?  
Буду рад узнать для себя что-то новое.  
А до тех пор вам самое оно глубже изучать паттерны програмирования и ООП, ибо попахивает каким-то хитрым паттерном.  
P.s. Мусье занет толк )
P.p.s. Уточню, меня интересует язык программирования, который позволяет из родителя создать какой-то конкретный объект дочернего типа. На фоне того что дочек может быть оч много это выглядит маловероятным.

Comment: А как это у вас возможно два одинаковых по имени файла?

Comment: Ну на самом деле из ЯП я знаю только php... ну и посмел предположить, что можно так сделать... По моему это оправданно и логично, как мне кажется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@Аркадий Кожедуб](/users/10582/%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1)](/users/10582/%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1) кончилось место для комметнов так что напишу сюда
То что вы предположили без изрядной доли извращения сделать не возможно.
Очень советую изучить пару других ЯП(например Си и Java) и теорию вообще.

P.s. допускаю что я могу не знать про какую-то финчу с динамическим(или тут правильно сказать анонимным?) наследованием.

**Update**
В родительский класс можно добавить метод выплёвывающий объект дочернего класса, но как мне кажется это не то что вы имели ввиду.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам помогут псевдонимы для namespace

```
use Name_class as NameClassController
use Name_class as NameClassModel
```